# Uploading file to storage without extension

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to create an app where users can upload files to the "wall". The idea is not important. Each file is added both to storage and to database as [fileName : url) under user's profile. Because of limitations regarding strings in database, I keep filenames without extensions (can't use dot symbol). Uploading works fine but I have a problem with deletion. Based on the file user picks to delete in app I get the filename(without extension). My delete function should delete the file from storage but it cannot locate file because of missing extension.
I use this function to upload the data:

```
let uploadTask = ref.putData(contents as Data, metadata: myMetadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in ...}
```

and the file itself:

```
let contents = try Data(contentsOf: url.standardizedFileURL)
```

Is it possible to upload "contents" without the extension? Or maybe is there another approach I'm missing?

Thanks for tips.

Comment: Can you substitute the "." symbol with another symbol when storing the url as a String, and then swap it out when you're calling your delete function?  Like "|" or something?  If a user tries to delete "image|jpg" you just swap the | for a . and delete "image.jpg"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is the only solution I have right now. However it would imply, that in the app users would see "test|jpg" which is not appropriate. That's why I am trying to find different solution.

Comment: Depending of how you are presenting things to the user, you could set up a "translator" - for instance, if `||` stands for `.`, call this "translator" to present either one to the user/URL. (And since the "URL encoding" for a period is `%2E`, maybe make it that?)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a really good idea to store the names of random things (including files) as keys in Realtime Database.  You could make this easier on yourself by pushing an object at a location in the database for each file uploaded.  The pushed object could contain the name and location of the file in Storage, along with any other metadata about that file, and you won't have to mangle that data as long as it's stored in values rather than keys.